# Adding Contacts.contactdown to TagVisualization

Tags: pixelsense, ellipse

I am working with TagVisualization, which displays an ellipse around the tag with name. I want to put 2 round buttons on the circumference (at well defined points) on the ellipse so that clicking them will result in change of some label text. I am unable to do this because I am unable to add `s:Contacts.ContactDown` property to the smaller ellipse.

Below is the XAML:

```
<s:TagVisualization x:Class="ControlsBox.TagVisual"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
Loaded="TagVisual_Loaded">
<Canvas>

    <Ellipse Width="300" Height="300" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="8" Opacity="0.7">
        <Ellipse.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="12" />
        </Ellipse.Effect>
    </Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Height="296" Width="296" Stroke="AntiqueWhite" StrokeThickness="4" >
        <Ellipse.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="4"/>
        </Ellipse.Effect>   
    </Ellipse>
    <Label Content="John's Phone" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0,250,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" IsHitTestVisible="false">
        <Label.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="9" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Aqua"/>
        </Label.Effect>
    </Label>

    <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,70,0,0" Fill="Black" 
       s:Contacts.ContactDown="UNABLE_TO_ADD" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: You're gonna have to ask a better question... is there an error?  what does it say?  what behavior are you seeing that is different from your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

After doing bit of googling, it appeared that using Expression Blend to create buttons with a style is an easier option.